# Can I link audio thats not local into my html file?

Tags: html, audio

My hosting doesn't allow me to upload mp3 or any audio files, so is there any way I can link audio in some other way? I know we can embed soundcloud and stuff but just wondering if there was any other alternative.

Comment: Yes: soundcloud and stuff. Audio can load from anywhere

Comment: _I know we can embed soundcloud and stuff but just wondering if there was any other alternative._

Comment: alternative to `stuff` is `other stuff`

Comment: [`<audio src="https://anywherethatallowsit.com/anysound.mp3" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Comment: `<audio
        controls
        src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>`
does this audio tag work for embeds?

Comment: That is HOW to embed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the best way to do it without uploading your audio/music, **BASE64 ENCODING!!**

Very easy, kinda messy and supposed to be used for images I guess but works fine with audios and should work with videos as well (haven't tried videos)

Here a base64 encoder: https://omatsuri.app/b64-encoding

*WARNING THOUGH! IT MIGHT GET LAGGY & MESSY*

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found this very useful [guide](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000071.htm#:%7E:text=Linking%20to%20a%20sound%20file,directly%20into%20a%20web%20page) that covers some alternatives:

> Linking to a sound file using a href allows a browser to open and play
> an audio file if the viewer of your web page has properly configured
> their Internet browser. You can also use the  tag or the newer
>  tag to insert a sound file directly into a web page.

### `<a href>` tag

```html
<a href="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3">Play sound 
file</a>
```

### `<audio>` tag

The  tag can create a media player as part of the web page. It allows the visitor to play, stop, pause, or download an audio file. The  element is compatible with all modern web browsers.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3" />
</audio>
```

### `<embed>` tag

An older method of including audio files is to use the  tag. While this method certainly works, it is less efficient than those which were mentioned above. As such, we recommend using one of the solutions demonstrated above.

```html
<embed src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3">
```